# How to define chained calculations in Pyomo model?

Tags: python, pyomo

I am not sure that I am modelling the constraints correctly. I have the chain-type calculations in my model, meaning that the `balance_equation` should use the values of previously calculated `power_rule` and `weight_rule`. Please see a simplified example below.

```
def power_rule(model, r, t):
    return model.v[r,t] == 25*model.x[r,t].value
model.power_flow = Constraint(model.R, model.T, rule=power_rule)

def weight_rule(model, r, t):
    return model.z[r,t] == 5*model.x[r,t].value
model.weight_flow = Constraint(model.R, model.T, rule=weight_rule)

def balance_equation(model, r, t):
    if t == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    return model.w[r,t] == model.w[r,t-1].value + model.v[r,t] - model.z[r,t].value
model.flow = Constraint(model.R, model.T, rule=balance_equation)
```

Previously, I initialized `w`, `v` and `z` with 0 for all `t` and `r` index values. This does not seem logical for me. I would expect to only initialize `w[r,0]` and then the calculation of the rest of values should be chained.

However, it looks like the chain calculation is not executed and the variables `v` and `z` are not updated, remaining the same all the time.
What is wrong in my aproach? Should I use `model.power_flow` and `model.weight_flow` instead of `model.v` and `model.z`? If so, any example would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use `.value` in a constraint expression. This causes the current value of a variable to be used in the expression instead of the variable itself, i.e. when the value of the variable changes the expression will not be updated. Even after removing `.value`, **the constraints will only be satisfied after sending the model to a solver**. This means you have to initialize each variable independently, there is no automated infrastructure for "chaining" the initialization calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Ok, I removed `value` from everywhere. Could you please clarify what you mean by "you have to initialize each variable independently"? I initialize variables as follows: `model.v = Var(model.R, model.T)` and then `for r in model.R: for t in model.T: model.v[r,t] = 0`. Is it what you mean?

Comment: If you want to initialize every index of a variable to the same value then you could do something like: `model.v = Var(model.R, model.T, initialize=0)`. What I meant by my statement is that initializing `model.v` to 0 will have no effect on the initialization (current value) of `model.x` even though they are related in your `power_flow` constraint. The constraints are not enforced until the model is successfully solved by a solver.